# Cascading - how to Read delimiter separated file and get specific field value

Tags: java, cascading

I am trying to use Cascading to read an delimiter separated file and trying to read a specific field.

**Code sample:**

```
FileTap inTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited( true, "," ), "C://Users//user//Desktop//test//file.txt");
```

**File Content:**

```
name,age,email
```

How do i get only `name` field from all the records?

Update: I am trying to achieve this using Cascading API classes.

Comment: @Chris311 : I am trying to do this using Cascading API Classes not with Plain Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the TextLine Scheme instead of the TextDelimited Scheme,

```
new Hfs(new cascading.scheme.hadoop.TextLine(asSourceFields), filePath, SinkMode.REPLACE);
```

After you read a line from this source tap, you have to use a `cascading.operation.Function` to split the line and create a tuple that contains only the 'name' field.

Here's an example,

```
public class SplitLine extends BaseOperation implements Function {

    public SplitLine() {
        super(1, new Fields("name"));
    }

    @Override
    public void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess, FunctionCall functionCall) {
        TupleEntry arguments = functionCall.getArguments();

        String line = arguments.getString(0);
        String[] tokens = line.split("\t");

        // Check that the split worked as assumed.
        if (tokens.length == 3) {
            Tuple output = new Tuple("name");
            output.set(0, tokens[0]);

            functionCall.getOutputCollector().add(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.